# Using <input type="file"> with a FTP value

Tags: php, ftp, input

Is it possible to get access to a file on my FTP doing the following?

```
<input type="file" name="final" id="final" value="http://www.blah.com.au/artwork/<?=$OrderID?>/<?=$ItemID?>/Final/Final.pdf">;
```

I know that this specifically didn't work for me, but is there a way to get the file from the FTP so I can send the information to the next page to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. Why not use PHP to retrieve the file from your FTP or HTTP site yourself? A simple `file_get_contents()` will suffice (yes, it works for FTP and HTTP links).

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents('http://www.blah.com.au/artwork/'.$OrderID.'/'.$ItemID.'/Final/Final.pdf');
```

### Edit

Based on new information, you might want to provide a select box with all the files on the ftp folder. You may do so by using [`ftp_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php), [`ftp_login()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php), [`ftp_nlist()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) and [`ftp_close()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-close.php)

```
<?php

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

// output $contents
var_dump($contents);

?>
```

Comment: When i tried this i just got an error

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.blah.com.au/artwork/15005/16800/Final/Final.pdf) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Comment: Sorry this could be my stuff up

Comment: It gets all the information, but when trying to attach it to an email it doesn't work, but i think that the function just grabs the contents and not the actual file.

Comment: @Craig: That function grabs what's inside the file. If you want to copy the file to your local file system, use `copy()` instead.

Comment: ended up using the first option then using this in PhpMailer
$mail->AddStringAttachment($file_contents, 'Final', 'base64','pdf');

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible. File type input elements are used for uploading files from the client's machine to the web server. They cannot pull remote content. This is a restriction of the HTML standard.

What do you want to accomplish with this? Perhaps there is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am automating a proofing system for artwork, but we keep having people selecting the wrong files to uploading (through incompetence?). So I am writing it so the users will not have to select the file to attach the e-mail.

All they will have to do is select the client, it will write the e-mail and attach the image from the FTP which is where the artists uploads the final image to.

So I just need to be able to attach the file directly from FTP to an e-mail made by [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/). The only other way I see of doing this is to store the image in the database as data, but I don't think I want to explore that option.